# Gitlab API download file + RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, resttemplate

Please help with following problem.

When I try to do request to gitlab with Postman or curl everithing works fine, I got answer with the file

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxx" "https://gitlabXXXX/api/v4/projects/13/repository/files/src%2Fcom%2Fgre%2Fjenkins%2FConstants.groovy?ref=foo"
```

But when I try to do the same in code I get error with this message = "404 File not found"

```
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "xxxxxxx");
    System.out.println(restTemplate.exchange("https://gitlabXXXX/api/v4/projects/13/repository/files/src%2Fcom%2Fgre%2Fjenkins%2FConstants.groovy?ref=foo", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), String.class).getBody());
```

Why it does not work? Maybe something in RestTempate change the URL or I do not know...

Answer (score 3):

RestTemplate encodes your URL once again, so your request URL is:

`https://gitlabXXXX/api/v4/projects/13/repository/files/src%252Fcom%252Fgre%252Fjenkins%252FConstants.groovy?ref=foo`

So your `%` turns into `%25` and this is not what gitlab API is waiting for.

#### Solution

You can use `UriComponentsBuilder.build(true)` method to tell your URI is already encoded:

```
String gitlabUriString = "https://gitlabXXXX/api/v4/projects/13/repository/files/src%2Fcom%2Fgre%2Fjenkins%2FConstants.groovy?ref=foo";

// true in build(true) tells parameters are already encoded
URI gitlabUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(gitlabUriString)
    .build(true).toUri();

System.out.println(restTemplate.exchange(gitlabUri, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders), String.class).getBody());
```

Comment: Thank you for answer) So why it does not work? And how it makes to work?

Comment: Edited my answer, try using UriComponentsBuilder